# How to work with members of sequence during iteration with expl3?

Tags: environments, expl3, etoolbox, hooks

I have several environments before and after which I want to insert identical code. I want to do this using `expl3` because in my opinion it is the best solution. But my solution does not work because `##1` does not seem to expand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_const_from_clist:Nn\g__env_seq{equation,temp@env,align,multline}
\seq_map_inline:cn{g__env_seq}{
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{##1}{\message{before~##1}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{##1}{\message{after~##1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{test@env}{\message{start~of~environment}}{\message{end~of~environment}}
\begin{equation}
x=0
\end{equation}
\begin{test@env}
some text
\end{test@env}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to double `#` there. You need to double hashes every time you are referring to the parameters of a macro which is inside the definition of another macro. For instance, if you do:

```
\def\testout#1{%
  \def\testin##1{(#1) and (##1)}%
}
\testout{a} % This line does \def\testin#1{(a) and (#1)}
\testin{b} % this line prints "(a) and (b)"
```

the parameter `#1` refers to the argument of the macro `\testout`, while the parameter `##1` refers to the argument of `\testin`. This applies to `\seq_map_inline:Nn` because:
`\seq_map_inline:Nn <seq var> {<code>}` basically does `\def\temp#1{<code>}` and then calls `\temp` for every item in the `<seq var>`. Since you are calling `\seq_map_inline:Nn` from outside any macro definition, the hashes in the `<code>` don't need to be doubled. If, on the other hand, you do something like:

```latex
\cs_new:Npn \test:
  {
    \seq_map_inline:Nn <seq var> { <code> }
  }
```

then the hashes in the `<code>` need to be doubled because they are inside the definition of `\test:`.

This applies to more levels of nesting macro definitions. Each definition inside another definition has to double the hashes:

```
\def\testa#1{%
  \def\testb##1{%
    \def\testc####1{%
      \def\testd########1{%
        a(#1), b(##1), c(####1), and d(########1) :-)
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
```

---

Fix that and your code prints (I replaced `\message` by `\iow_term:n` to get line breaks):

```
before equation
after equation
start of environment
end of environment
```

I also changed a few other things in your code. As egreg said in the comment, `\g__env_seq` is not a good name for a variable, since it lacks a module name. Also, since you define it with `\seq_const_from_clist:Nn`, the variable is a constant, so the name should begin with `\c_...` instead of `\g_...`. A better name would be `\c_kozlovskiy_env_seq` (the two underscores are not necessary because it's not a variable internal to a package).

Also, since you seem to be using this list only once, there is no need to define a variable for that: you can use `\clist_map_inline:nn` directly.

Working code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn { equation , temp@env , align , multline }
  {
    \BeforeBeginEnvironment {#1} { \iow_term:n { before~#1 } }
    \AfterEndEnvironment {#1} { \iow_term:n { after~#1 } }
  }
\newenvironment{test@env}
  { \iow_term:n {start~of~environment} }
  { \iow_term:n {end~of~environment} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{equation}
x=0
\end{equation}
\begin{test@env}
some text
\end{test@env}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\g__env_seq` is a bad name: it should be something like `\c_kozlovskiy_env_seq`

Comment: @egreg True. I added a note. Thanks!

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Please see the edit :-)